# Cannot use explicitly typed lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have this code:

```
std::function<std::string&(std::string&)> change_str = [](std::string& str){
    return (str = "Hello world!");
};

std::string s;

std::cout << change_str(s) << std::endl;
```

It does not compile, and say:

```
main.cpp:8:47: error: no viable conversion from '(lambda at main.cpp:8:60)' to 'std::function<std::string &(std::string &)>'
    std::function<std::string&(std::string&)> change_str = [](std::string& str){
                                              ^            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1448:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '(lambda at main.cpp:8:60)' to 'nullptr_t' for 1st argument
    function(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __f_(0) {}
    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1449:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '(lambda at main.cpp:8:60)' to 'const std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > &(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > &)> &' for 1st argument
    function(const function&);
    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1450:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '(lambda at main.cpp:8:60)' to 'std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > &(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > &)> &&' for 1st argument
    function(function&&) _NOEXCEPT;
    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:1454:41: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Fp = (lambda at main.cpp:8:60)]
                                        __callable<_Fp>::value &&
                                        ^
main.cpp:8:60: note: candidate function
    std::function<std::string&(std::string&)> change_str = [](std::string& str){
                                                           ^
1 error generated.
```

However if I change the declaration of `std::function` to `auto`, then it works:

```
auto change_str = ...
```

Why is the explicit type not working for lambda?

Comment: Note that `std::function` is not "explicitly typed lambda". That is, `std::function` is not just for lambdas (also, lambdas aren't special). It can store every `f` that can be called like `f(args)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A lambda with no return type is `auto`, and auto remove the external reference, so you are not returning `string&` but just `string`.

Just declare the functional as

```
std::function<std::string&(std::string&)> change_str = 
[](std::string& str) -> string&  ///<--- NOTE THIS
{
    return (str = "Hello world!");
};
```

Comment: *"A lambda with no return type is `auto`"* Which means, in C++14, we could use `-> decltype(auto)`, but that could be considered obscure.

Comment: @dyp: the problem is that `auto` applied to a `decltype` that is a reference in not like decltype of an auto that's not by itself a reference... Yes: it's *obscure*, at least until it will become a well established idiom... in 2017

Answer (score 4):

Deduced return type for your lambda is `std::string`, that's why your declaration does not match. But when you explicitly specify return type, it works:

```
std::function<std::string&(std::string&)> change_str = 
        [](std::string& str) -> std::string& 
{
    return (str = "Hello world!");
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As others say, the issue is that the default return type deduction deduces `std::string` which is not compatible with the expected `std::string&`.

Catalogue of the various declarations to solve this:

```
// be completely explicit about the return type
[](std::string& str) -> std::string& {

 // be explicit about returning lvalue reference
[](std::string& str) -> auto& {

// be explicit that you're returning some kind of reference type,
// but use reference collapsing to determine if it's an lvalue or rvalue reference
[](std::string& str) -> auto&& { 

// use C++14 feature to deduce reference type
[](std::string& str) -> decltype(auto) {
```

These are listed in order of least to most generic. However in this case there's no particular need for genericity: you were only deducing the return type because that's the default/least typing. Of these I'd probably say being explicit is probably the best: `[](std::string &str) -> std::string& {`

quantdev deleted his answer which I think makes another good suggestion:

```
[](std::string& str) {
    return std::ref(str = "Hello world!");
};
```

This works because `std::function` only requires suitable convertibility to/from the argument and return types, and returning the result of `std::ref` here meets that requirement.

Both using `std::ref` and using an explicit `std::string &` return type seem readable to me. With optimizations on my implementation produces exactly the same thing for both, so if you prefer the look of `std::ref` there's little reason not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

A lambda with no return type behaves as `auto` which follows the [Template Argument Deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) rules and your return type is deduced to be `std::string` and not `std::string&`

If the type gets specified explicitly everything's fine

```
std::function<std::string&(std::string&)> change_str = 
                                 [](std::string& str) -> std::string& {
  return (str = "Hello world!");
};
```